# May unsynchronized updates at a given array index disturb the values of adjacent indices in a concurrency setting, as per the JVM / JMM?

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm, java-memory-model

Let's consider that I have two threads `T1` and `T2` and that those threads attempt to update array `A` at random indices:

```
final int[] A = new int[10];
```

My questions are:

1. Given that stores / loads of 32 bit fields are guaranteed to be atomic, can we make the assumption that unsynchronized sets on `A`, of the form `A[x] = random_value` are always "correctly set"?
2. If they are correctly set, are we guaranteed that they won't possibly change the values of nearby array indices? For instance, could setting `A[3] = 666` change the value of `A[2]` or `A[4]`, as they're with high probability in the same cache line?
3. Would questions 1. or 2. change if instead of an `int` array we had a `long`, `byte`, or `boolean` array?

Thanks

Comment: [JLS §17.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.6) and [§17.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7) are specifically about your questions.

Comment: @apangin thx, exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: My question now would then be: does that imply that boolean arrays need to then be implemented as byte arrays (at least on x86), as that's the minimum size supported by the architecture allowing atomic read / stores?

Comment: No. As long as JVM can ensure [observable] atomicity by other means, e.g. CAS.

Comment: But is that what happens in practice?

Comment: Apparently they are indeed stored as one byte per array index: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.baload -> " In Oracle's Java Virtual Machine implementation, boolean arrays - that is, arrays of type T_BOOLEAN (§2.2, §newarray) - are implemented as arrays of 8-bit values."

Comment: If there is a data race between the read and the write, it doesn't really matter what the hardware offers in the atomicity department. The compiler can completely mess things up; e.g. getting rid of the load/store.

Answer (score 1):

As per @apaganin's comment:

1 and 2. Yes:

> 17.6. Word Tearing
> One consideration for implementations of the Java Virtual Machine is that every field and array element is considered distinct; updates to one field or element must not interact with reads or updates of any other field or element. In particular, two threads that update adjacent elements of a byte array separately must not interfere or interact and do not need synchronization to ensure sequential consistency.

> Some processors do not provide the ability to write to a single byte. It would be illegal to implement byte array updates on such a processor by simply reading an entire word, updating the appropriate byte, and then writing the entire word back to memory. This problem is sometimes known as word tearing, and on processors that cannot easily update a single byte in isolation some other approach will be required.

3. Yes.

Comment: Your third question was “Would questions 1. or 2. change…” and the answer is *no*. The cited text says “some other approach will be required” when the underlying architecture doesn’t provide it on its own, which means, it’s the JVM vendor’s problem. In case of HotSpot, for example, `boolean[]` arrays use a byte per entry, so it doesn’t depend on atomic bit operations. The only problem is the meaning of “correctly set” in your first question. And the issue of potential word tearing with `long`, but that’s not an array specific issue.